# Customized Interactive Input Range with Google Charts (Pie Chart)

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

How does one combine a customized input range with the google charts pie chart to create an interactive graph?

The goal is for the Pie chart to display different percentages based on the position of the "input range."

`var PercentageDeterminedBySlider` would be a percent variable that changes based on the sliders position 1 through 5. The pie chart would then display this percentage.

***code for pie chart***

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartPie);

function drawChartPie() {

  var profitVar2 = PercentageDeterminedBySlider;
  var other= 100-profitVar2;

  var data3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Name', 'Profit Percentage'],
    ['Your Profit Percentage' , profitVar2],
    ['Potential for Growth', other]
  ]);

  var options3 = {
    title: 'Profit Percentage',
    legend: 'none',
    is3D: true,
    pieSliceText: 'value',
  };

  var chart3 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_divPie'));

  chart3.draw(data3, options3);
}
```

***code for input Range***

```html
<label for="points">Rating:</label>
<input type="text" id="textInput" value="5">
<input type="range" name="points" id="points" value="5" min="1" max="5" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);">
```

***Click below to see example***

**Example Image**

[image]

Lastly, there is a slider(aka input range) integrated with Google charts on the Google website, however its' functionality appears to be very limited. So the goal here is to create a custom slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, there are some problems in your code. Here is some:

1. You can get the var `PercentageDeterminedBySlider` using `document.querySelector('#points').value`.
2. When the input change you can call again the method `drawChartPie`. It will take the updated value from the `range`.

Pay attention that you need to use `praseInt` to convert the range's value to int so the chart will work.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartPie);

function drawChartPie() {
  var profitVar2 = parseInt(document.querySelector('#points').value);
  var other = 100 - profitVar2;

  var data3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Name', 'Profit Percentage'],    
    ['Your Profit Percentage' , profitVar2],
    ['Potential for Growth', other]
  ]);

  var options3 = {
    title: 'Profit Percentage',
    legend: 'none',
    is3D: true,
    pieSliceText: 'value',
  };

  var chart3 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_divPie'));

  chart3.draw(data3, options3);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<label for="points">Rating:</label>
<input type="text" id="textInput" value="5">
<input type="range" name="points" id="points" value="5" min="1" max="5" onchange="drawChartPie()">
<div id="chart_divPie"></div>
Click
```

http://output.jsbin.com/fawehez

Comment: I think this is awesome. I will test it and then give more feedback. Much appreciated.

Comment: My pleasure :) I hope that it will answer your question.. let me know..